# What does pink-sheet mean related to stocks?

Tags: investing, stocks, terminology, stock-exchanges, pink-sheets

I see the term pink-sheet mentioned a lot in context of stocks. What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [an over-the-counter stock quote system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_Sheets). Read all about it. Or [visit it](http://www.otcmarkets.com/pink/index.jsp).